# How should routesImport be defined in build.sbt in Play 2.3?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

I'm upgrading a project from Play 2.2 to 2.3.0.

The following `routesImport` line in `build.sbt` stopped resolving and Play says `val not found error`:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

routesImport += "binders._"
```

I can't find any documentation for 2.3.x that would explain how to migrate this. Please advise.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`routesImports` is in `import play.PlayImport.PlayKeys._`

Comment: That should be `routesImport`.

Comment: Funny...didn't see this in the migration guide, or documented elsewhere.

Comment: And it changed again in 2.4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900153/play-2-4-value-routesimport-is-not-a-member-of-object-play-play-autoimport-playk/34043562#34043562