# Play 2.4 value routesImport is not a member of object play.Play.autoImport.PlayKeys

Tags: playframework-2.4

I am getting this error after migrating to 2.4 from 2.3. What is the right import statement I should use?

```
error: value routesImport is not a member of object play.Play.autoImport.PlayKeys
    PlayKeys.routesImport += "se.radley.plugin.salat.Binders._",
```

I have these import statements:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Play.autoImport._
import PlayKeys._
import WebKeys._
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
import play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys
...
RoutesKeys.routesImport += "se.radley.plugin.salat.Binders._"
```